# Mockery not mocking previously required modules?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocking

views.js

```
controllers = require '../../modules/fixture/controllers.js'
exports.custom = (db) ->
  (req, res) ->
    controllers.custom req.body
      , (result) ->
        res.json result : result
      , (error) ->
        res.json 400, error : error
```

test.js

```
mockery = require "mockery"

exports.tests = (app, db, config) ->
  describe '#routes', ->
    describe '/fixture/custom', ->
      it 'should return status 400 if no request body was provided', (done) ->
        request app
          .post '/fixture/custom'
          .send
            body :
              players : []
          .expect 400, done

  describe '#views', ->
    describe '#custom', ->
      controller =
        custom : (body, success_callback, error_callback) ->
          console.log "###MOCK CONTROLLER BODY: #{req}"
          if body
            success_callback 'result'
          else
            error_callback 'error'
      mockery.enable()
      mockery.registerAllowable '../../modules/fixture/controllers.js', true
      mockery.registerMock '../../modules/fixture/controllers.js', controller

      it 'should return json keyed by result on success callback', (done) ->
        req =
          body : true
        res.json = (response) ->
          response.result.should.eql 'result'
          done()
        custom req, res
```

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined` which I have confirmed is due to my mock not getting registered as I'd like.

I'm thinking the problem is that `require(../../modules/fixture/controllers.js)` is happening before `test.tests(app, db, config)` is called, and so the require cache is already created.

Shouldn't `mockery.registerAllowable('../../modules/fixture/controllers.js', true)` allow me to override already required modules? I require quite a lot of switching between real and mock modules throughout many tests, so I'd prefer to be able to register mocks "just in time" rather than all at the beginning, for instance before instantiating my express app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used this in the past to get rid of the modules I had loaded before enable mockery:

```
mockery.enable({ useCleanCache: true });
```

With this option, the [cache of modules is flushed](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery#controlling-the-module-cache) before enabling mockery.

Comment: I was facing problems in Yeoman angular-fullstack project. Tests run fine with only Mocha from but failed with 'grunt test'. The mock I created with Mockery was not loaded in tests. This was apparently due some other test/setup that had required the module I was testing earlier and thus it was cached. Using the 'useCleanCache: true' as adviced did the trick for me.